# Using ids of a MDTextField in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, dialog, kivymd, ids

Here, I am having a MDTextfield that should take values as I type on the characters on the keyboard. But for some reason, the characters are clickable and respond, but they do not get written into the MDTextfield. SO I tried with creating  function called write_text() (just in case of the letter "a") and then do its implementation in the Python file. But this requires me to address the id of that MDTextField in my python file. That is where the problem is.

Here is my kivy code (the part we are interested in is , at the bottom)

```
#:import MyLayout main2.MyLayout

MyLayout:
    MDLabel:
        id: task_label
        halign: "center"
        markup: True
        text:"[b][u][size=48]Your Task Manager[/size][/u][/b]"
        pos_hint: {"y": 0.45}
    ScrollView:
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5}
        size_hint: 0.9, 0.8
        MDList:
            id: container

    OneLineListItem:
        text: "Clickable Area for adding task"
        on_release: app.clickable_item()

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "plus-thick"
        on_release: app.task_dialog()
        elevation_normal: 12
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "y": 0.04}


<TaskDialogContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: task_text
            hint_text: "Add a task ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: (app.add_task(task_text.text), app.close_task_dialog())


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: (app.add_task(task_text.text), app.close_task_dialog())
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_task_dialog()


<SubTaskDialogContent>:
    id: subtask_content 
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: subtask_text
            hint_text: "Add a subtask ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_subtask_dialog()


<SubTaskShowContent>:
orientation: "vertical"

ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        id: subtasks_grid
        cols: 1
        spacing: dp(5)


<KeyboardContent>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTextField:
        id: text_input
        hint_text: "Type here"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 6
        spacing: "10dp"

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "A"
            on_release:
                app.write_text(text_input.text)
                app.speak_text("a")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "B"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("b")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "C"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("c")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "D"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("d")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "E"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("e")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "F"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("f")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "G"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("g")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "H"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("h")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "I"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("i")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "J"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("j")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "K"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("k")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "L"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("l")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "M"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("m")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "N"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("n")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "O"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("o")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "P"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("p")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Q"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("q")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "R"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("r")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "S"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("s")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "T"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("t")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "U"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("u")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "V"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("v")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "W"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("w")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "X"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("x")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Y"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("y")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Z"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += self.text
                app.speak_text("z")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Space"
            on_release:
                text_input.text += " "
                app.speak_text("space")

        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            text: "Delete"
            icon: "backspace-outline"
            on_release:
                app.speak_text("delete")
                text_input.text = text_input.text[:-1]

        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            text: "Done"
            icon: "check-all"
            on_release:
                app.add_task(text_input.text)
                app.close_keyboard_dialog()
                app.speak_text("Done. Task Added successfully.")
```

And here is the implementation of write_text() in the python file.

```
    def write_text(self, sometext):
        text_input = self.root.ids.keyboard_content.ids.text_input
        text_input.text += sometext
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to write code to make an `MDTextField` do what it is designed to do. There must be something else going on in your code. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.